# How to mask stock command in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, paths

I have a function that I run often from the CLI, so I gave it the short name `t`:

```
$ which t
/home/dotancohen/.bin/t

$ cat `which t`
#!/bin/bash
ctags-exuberant -f php.tags --languages=PHP -R

$ ls -lh /home/dotancohen/.bin/t
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dotancohen dotancohen 316 Jan  3 16:58 /home/dotancohen/.bin/t

$ echo $PATH
/home/dotancohen/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/dotancohen/.rvm/bin
```

However, when I try to run the program, I get a message that I should install another app that also uses the name `t`:

```
$ t
The program 'task' is currently not installed. To run 'task' please ask your administrator to install the package 'taskwarrior'
```

How can I have Bash run `/home/dotancohen/.bin/t` when I enter `t`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you have `t` defined as an alias (or a function), you can find it using the `type` builtin:

```
type -a t
```

Aliases, functions (and other shell builtins) take precedence over external executables.

To run the executable `t` from your `PATH`, do:

```
't'
```

Or

```
"t"
```

Or

```
\t
```

Note that, just `t` is not a good name for a file.

Comment: I completely forgot that `t` was an alias that I had set up years ago when I used TaskWarrior. I thought that it was the built-in name! **Thank you!**

Comment: @dotancohen Let me stress that the bottom line is: don't use `which` to understand what a command does, since `which` only reports executables, and rather use the (more portable) `type`, which can detect functions, aliases etc (and it's a shell builtin, so it will always works as long as you're using a shell which supports it).